# How to compose a layout like this?

Tags: html, css

The first image here is a draft created by web-designers.
[image]

The second image here is my result of creating a proper HTML/CSS layout for this.
[image]

The question is: how can i create this transparent field around a rating pill using only proper HTML5 and CSS. Solution must be cross-browser and super-compatible (including IE7 and higher).

The rating pill width is not fixed, it depends on number inside it, so the transparent field must reflect this.

Here's my current layout:

```
<div class="evo-module-c4b style="background-image: url('/i/oranges.jpg');">

    <div class="price">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="value">10,950</span>
    </div>

    <div class="die"></div>

    <div class="rating-wrapper">
        <div class="evo-rating">
            <span class="value">+100500</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
        <p class="author">Donec et</p>
        <p class="data">24.08.2012 10:53</p>
        <h3>Nunc pellentesque justo diam, sed dictum dolor.</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

LESS:

```
div.evo-module-c4b {
    position: relative;
    width: @module-big-width;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: @color-gray-1;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;

    div.price {
        position: absolute;
        top: 18px;
        right: 24px;
        span.icon {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            background-image: url('/i/evo/icons-imageset.png');
            background-position: -20px 0;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        span.value {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 4px;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: @color-white;
        }
    }

    div.die {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 108px;
        background-color: @color-gray-10;
        //background-image: url('/i/evo/modules/c4b/die.png');
        background-position: 0 0;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    div.rating-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 122px;
        text-align: center;
        div.evo-rating {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }

    div.content {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 172px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;

        h2, h3, p {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            line-height: normal;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        p.author {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        p.data {
            font-size: 10px;
            color: @color-gray-4;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 12px;
            color: @color-gray-4;
        }
    }
}

div.evo-rating {
    span.value {
        .evo-border-radius(@rating-height / 2 + 3px);
        display: block;
        height: @rating-height;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: @rating-height;
        color: @color-major;
        background-color: @color-white;
        border: 3px solid @color-major;
        padding: 0 5px;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? )

Comment: I don't think it's going to be possible to completely achieve, though the closest solution is likely to involve creating an element the same as the pill but larger, absolutely positioning it and giving it a background image offset rather than making anything actually transparent.

Comment: Could you show us what the HTML for (and directly around) the rating pill looks like? That way, we know what elements are in play and what we will be manipulating. I think this is important to being able to come up with a good solution.

Comment: Actually you can change the code however you like, but i will post my current layout right now.

Comment: moopet, actually it's a great idea! I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: It may be possible with a mask, but I think only webkit supports that

Comment: @moopet can you post your comment as an answer to this question? In my opinion your solution is most simple and elegant, and it works perfectly. I need to figure out some little things with IE though )

Comment: I have actually already built an answer with fiddle from moopet's comment after messing around in jsFiddle for a while. Sorry moopet, I didn't mean to steal your glory. The reason I started fiddeling in the first place was due to the great idea you presented. I credited your contribution while writing the answer. Hope it's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's going to be possible to completely achieve, though the closest solution is likely to involve:

Creating an element the same as the pill but larger. Absolute-position the new element  so it is underneath the pill but make it larger. Give it the same background image as the main "oranges" picture but and fiddle with its background position so that it lines up correctly. This will obviously depend on the implementation of the rest of your css.

Answer (score 2):

Change your grey background for an image with alpha for the hole and add it over the picture. You might need different sizes since the width might change.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't think that it's a really good idea. It will require to create a lot of grey images with different holes and server-side logic to apply appropriate image based on number of characters in rating's value. Too heavy. I'd like to find a more general solution.

Comment: The only other solution I would know would be to use Canvas and draw your own ellipse. But it's not cross browser. See: http://jsfiddle.net/jimrhoskins/dDUC3/1/

Comment: Also, you don't need to do the logic via the server. You can just have a js script that check the value (number of +1) and set the appropriate image. I suppose you won't need more than 5 or 6 different sizes. I know it's not the most elegant solution, but I know it works and is not too complicated to implement.

Comment: JavaScript is even worse in this case. It's poorly scallable solution. I think we've found a very nice approach today.

Answer (score 2):

*From the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109611/how-to-compose-a-layout-like-this/12112251#comment16187207_12109611) provided by [moopet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413354/moopet) I have constructed this answer and made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bakkerjoeri/R99NT/3/) illustrating his idea*

### Page structure

I'm working with the assumption that this is the HTML that structures your page:

```
<div class="picture">

  <div class="pill-wrapper">
    <div class="pill">+1030</div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
  </div>    

</div>​
```

### How will we approach this transparent pill border?

Working out the idea that [moopet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413354/moopet) gave us in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109611/how-to-compose-a-layout-like-this/12112251#comment16187207_12109611), you could absolutely position the .pill-wrapper (and find a correct center position using LESS variables*). Giving this .pill-wrapper a padding and border-radius, you can then use backgrounds to **create a faux transparent border**. Simply set the background to match picture that is shown and use `background-position` to match the rating pill's position on the page (again, usage of LESS variables will probably make this nice and easy).

### How does this translate to CSS?

Please study the CSS presented below. Note that only essential CSS is shown. Any font styling should be applied by yourself.

```
.picture {
  position: absolute;

  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;

  background: url('http://goo.gl/Zi4hw');
}

.pill {
  box-sizing: border-box;

  width: auto;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 5px;

  background: #0066aa;
  border-radius: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.pill-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 225px;
  left: 100px;

  height: 36px;
  padding: 10px;  

  background: url('http://goo.gl/Zi4hw') -100px -225px;
  border-radius: 36px;

}

.content {
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 250px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
```

There are definite problems with this method. Note firstly that, even though LESS will preprocess everything, it is not dynamic or fluid and additional Javascript should probably and regrettably work to account for keeping the pill centered during horizontal browser resizing, for instance. Secondly, there are probably some compatibility problems that should be looked into.

But the basics are here for you to work from.

You can see the proposed solution in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/bakkerjoeri/R99NT/3/

**: I have no experience coding in LESS, so my apologies for anything faulty I am assuming. Feel free to correct me.*

Comment: No need to absolutely position the pill. I finished this task the following way: i have three containers.

.pill-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.pill-alpha {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('...');
    background-position: x y;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.pill {
    border-radius: 3px;
}

The trick is to use the "text-align" style on the parent and "display: inline-block" style on the child element.

Comment: Thanks for you complete answer, but it was @moopet's idea first, so i marked his answer as correct one.

Comment: And it's padding of course on the second div, not border-radius in my comment = )

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's only fair. And I see what you did with the centering. Very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

As for me - there is no really simple solution. But I would try to combine a block with rating using few divs. Idea is that you can prepare few images with gray background where bottom half is gray and transparent at top. Problem with pill itself could be solved by combining it from 3(?) divs. One for left rounded border - that can be an image with border, gray background etc and transparent part, where your underlying image will be visible. One for rating itself and one for right rounded corner. All will have background images built in a way that being located side by side, they will make that pill. And now you just need to shift that all up on your top image.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, i've thought about this. Probably the only good solution i could imagine right now. But how could one make this divs to take appropriate widths? Probably i could solve it with tables, but i don't want to go that way yet.

TABLE:
[50%][left rounded corner][rating][right rounded corner][50%]

Answer (score 0):

If the pill is made with the selectors ":after" and ":before", you can create a gray div on the left and another on the right and entering the border radius near the pill as it but in the other side. Under the pill you can put a big grey one.